# iterating through folders and from each use one specific file in a method python

Tags: python

What I want to do is iterate through folders in a directory and in each folder find a file 'fileX' which I want to give to a method which itself needs the file name as a parameter to open it and get a specific value from it. So 'method' will extract some value from 'fileX' (the file name is the same in every folder).

My code looks something like this but I always get told that the file I want doesn't exist which is not the case:

```
import os 
import xy

rootdir =r'path' 

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(rootdir): 
    for file in files:
        gain = xy.method(fileX)
        print gain
```

Also my folders I am iterating through are named like 'folderX0', 'folderX1',..., 'folderX99', meaning they all have the same name with increasing ending numbers. It would be nice if I could tell the program to ignore every other folder which might be in 'path'.
Thanks for the help!

Comment: Are you giving just the file name to `method`? Or the file path plus the file name? There's a difference between `open("myfile.txt")` and `open("C:\users\uitty\desktop\myfile.txt")`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`os.walk`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.walk) returns file and directory names relative to the `root` directory that it gives. You can combine them with [`os.path.join`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.join):

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(rootdir): 
    for file in files:
        gain = xy.method(os.path.join(root, file))
        print gain
```

See the [documentation for `os.walk`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.walk) for details:

> To get a full path (which begins with top) to a file or directory in dirpath, do `os.path.join(dirpath, name)`.

To trim it to ignore any folders but those named `folderX`, you could do something like the following. When doing `os.walk` top down (the default), you can delete items from the `dirs` list to prevent `os.walk` from looking in those directories.

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(rootdir):
    for dir in dirs:
        if not re.match(r'folderX[0-9]+$', dir):
            dirs.remove(dir)
    for file in files:
        gain = xy.method(os.path.join(root, file))
        print gain
```

Comment: Sorry, missed the second part of your problem. Updated my answer to include that too.

Comment: thanks for updating! that is very helpful! but now I want to specify up to which number I want to go. So for example I there are folderX0,..,folderX99 folders in the directory but I only want to look into folders up to folderX49. How would I do that?

Comment: best keeping the range variable

Comment: @uitty400 Add a group to the regex and actually extract the number, then compare it to the range you are interested in: `max = 49; match = re.match(r'folderX([0-9]+)$', dir); if not match or int(match.group(1)) > max: dirs.remove(dir)`. Read up on [regular expressions](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html), in particular how to exctract information from [`MatchObject`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.MatchObject), and on the builtin [`int`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#int) for more details